# Why would anybody want

Tags: sentence-structure, modal-verbs

I want to know the meaning of "***Why would anybody want***" what does ***would*** mean here does it mean " ***Why did anybody want***" ? if the question is about the guy who's chasing them why the woman used anybody instead of this guy ?

Context: A woman and a man are chased by a another man inside a house,(*This man  set traps inside the house.*)They're trying to get out without him seeing them, They enter enter a room,  the woman  finds a machine that makes air cool **Turned On** she says: "**I don't get it.. why would anybody want to make this place any cooler? it's freezing**" and the man with her responds : "**God only knows what goes on inside this guy's head**."

Answer (score 2):

[The Cambridge Dictionary gives a meaning of "would":](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would) "used after 'why' when giving or asking the reason for something". I'll use an example it provides in order to explain why this writer uses "would" instead of "did".

> Why would anyone want to eat something so horrible?

This is more of a general statement; the speaker is not necessarily asking why a specific person did want to but why anybody might want to, at any point in time (past, present, or future). It is this general, all-encompassing meaning of "would" that serves as the backdrop for your speaker's question. The speaker doesn't understand this man's motivation for what he did in his specific circumstance--but then she doesn't understand *anyone's* motivation for doing the same thing, in any circumstance.

Not that she's necessarily thinking all that. It's just how we've learned to use the word.

Comment: what if we change anybody with somebody ? would that be general statement as well ? I learned to understand "Why would someone do this?" As "What motivated someone to do this" is that wrong ?

Comment: It will still be a general statement, yes. "Why would someone do this?" and "What motivated someone to do this?" are somewhat different. They both ask for motivation, but the former asks "why" rather more nebulously, while the latter asks "why" the way a detective asks "why". The former asks "why" vaguely, not necessarily expecting a concrete answer, but the latter asks "why" rationally, expecting some thought to go into the answer.

Comment: By the way, when you want to respond to someone's answer, please use "Add Comment".

Comment: Sorry, but the question is about the past motivation  whether it is why would someone do this or what motivated someone to do this , then it isn't a general statement because  we're asking about someone's past motivation not at any time right ?

Comment: It's a vague, general statement because you used the word "would". If you wanted to ask specifically about a certain someone's past motivation, you might use your second question, or something else concrete. But you wouldn't use the first one.

Comment: Yes – modals often indicate or at least suggest the non-actual. << "But someone  might eat the stuff in this display!" ...  "Why would anyone want to eat something so horrible?" >> is unsurprising. But << "Someone's  eaten some of the stuff in this display, and it's three weeks old!" ...  "Why would anyone want to eat something so horrible?" >> addresses an actual event; the overall unlikelihood of such events is what the modal points to.